# I need to wait for a request response in the main thread Android Studio

Tags: java, android, request

I need to make a request to an endpoint in the app startup, i really need to wait for the response to let the app continue running, so i need to make a sync request

how i can do it?

Comment: Did you try ClosableHTTPClient?

Comment: modern anroid develop _rarely_ needs sync api calls, that's not really a standard anymore. make the api call, show loading, wait for the response

Answer (score 0):

Any long-running sync request on the main thread will definitely trigger [Application Not Responding](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) (ANR) error.

It's [highly recommended](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#io_on_the_main_thread) to move each IO (network, storage) operation to a worker thread. To achieve this you can use a stack of [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html), [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi).

To prevent the app from running until the network response, you should implement [splash screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen). Configure its lifetime as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#suspend-drawing).

Answer (score 0):

> i really need to wait for the response to let the app continue running, so i need to make a sync request

No, you don't. You need to provide some temporary UI that does nothing (like a loading spinner) while the *async* request completes.

Read up on [coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?hl=de) for background work.

Making a "sync" request is just going to hang your app.